# Isotope overlapping .items because of featured images - HELP!

Tags: theme-development, images

I need urgent help as I'm having a nightmare with Isotope. All was working well through my desktop server but once live, Isotope items are overlapping (see http://www.skinsave.co.uk/30-2/)

How can I stop this from happening? I know why it is but my JS is rusty and I've been pasting in snippets without avail. Hard to see what changes what as it all looks fine on my desktop!

Here's the JS:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

            var $container = $('#isotope-list'); //The ID for the list with all the blog posts
            $container.isotope({ //Isotope options, 'item' matches the class in the PHP
            itemSelector: '.item'
            , layoutMode: 'masonry'



            });

             // init Isotope
                            var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
                                // options...
                            });
                            // layout Isotope after each image loads
                            $grid.imagesLoaded().progress(function () {
                                $grid.isotope('layout');
                            });

            container.imagesLoaded(function () {
            container.isotope({
                itemSelector: '.item'
            });
            })

            $(window).load(function () {
            $('.item').isotope('reLayout');
            });
            //Add the class selected to the item that is clicked, and remove from the others
            var $optionSets = $('#filters')
            , $optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

            $optionLinks.click(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            // don't proceed if already selected
            if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
                return false;
            }
            var $optionSet = $this.parents('#filters');
            $optionSets.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $this.addClass('selected');

            //When an item is clicked, sort the items.
            var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
            $container.isotope({
                filter: selector
            });



            return false;
            });

            success: function (data) {
            // Update isotope container with new data. 
            $container.isotope('remove', $container.data('isotope').$allAtoms)
            $container.isotope('insert', $(data))
                // trigger isotope again after images have been loaded
                .imagesLoaded(function () {
                    $container.isotope('reLayout');
                });
            }
            });

            });
```

and the PHP:

```
                    <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=50' ); //Check the WP_Query docs to see how you can limit which posts to display ?>
                        <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

                            <div id="isotope-list">
                                <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
            $termsArray = get_the_terms( $post->ID, "category" );  //Get the terms for this particular item
            $termsString = ""; //initialize the string that will contain the terms
                foreach ( $termsArray as $term ) { // for each term 
                    $termsString .= $term->slug.' '; //create a string that has all the slugs 
                }
            ?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"> <div class="<?php echo $termsString; ?> item" > <?php // 'blogpost' is used as an identifier (see Setp 5, line 6) ?>
                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                   <span id="thumbs"> <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
                              the_post_thumbnail();
                        } ?></span>
                     <h4><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> <?php the_date(); ?></h4>
            <h5><i class="fa fa-tags"></i> <?php $categories = get_the_category();

            if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
            echo esc_html( $categories[0]->name );   
            } ?> </h5><BR><BR>
                 <h6><?php the_subtitle(); ?></h6>
                <p>more <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
            </p>
```

Any help would be fantastic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page is loaded with jQuery errors (not using no-conflict), and additionally your isotope.js doesn't appear to be in no-conflict. This is why you're getting errors like $ is undefined.  Once you fix your jQuery by either replacing the $ with jQuery or wrapping your functions in

```
(function($) {
    $('selector');// Now you can use the $ to do whatever you want.

})( jQuery );
```

you should be in business.  Your first JS doc looks like it also has an extra }); at the end.  Then in your main page where you call the flex slider

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(window).load(function () {
                $('.flexslider').flexslider({
                    touch: true, // to allow for touch controls
                });
            });
        </script>
```

This is also the wrong, and need to be in no-conflict.

Try this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        (function($){   
            $(window).load(function () {
                $('.flexslider').flexslider({
                    touch: true, // to allow for touch controls
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);
 </script>
```

or just replace the $ with jQuery like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      jQuery(window).load(function () {
           jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({
                    touch: true, // to allow for touch controls
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Amazing! Worked perfectly after adding those in and adding (window).load(function to the isotope. Thanks!